# Unable to deploy the app on Moto360

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to deploy wear portion of the app on **Moto360** from **Android Studio 0.8.9**. At this point it is just a boiler plate code generated by Studio.

I am getting the following messages

```
Waiting for device.  
Target device: motorola-moto_360-localhost:4444  

Uploading file  
    local path: /<redacted>/wear/build/outputs/apk/wear-debug.apk  
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.[redacted]
Installing com.[redacted]  

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.[redacted]"  
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "libandroid_runtime.so" needed by "app_process"; caused by cannot locate symbol "uloc_toLcnguageTag_51" referenced by "libandroid_runtime.so"...


Launching application: com.[redacted]/com.[redacted].WearActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.[redacted]/com.[redacted].WearActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER  
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "libandroid_runtime.so" needed by "app_process"; caused by cannot locate symbol "uloc_toLcnguageTag_51" referenced by "libandroid_runtime.so"...
```

Moto360 is running **4.4W.1 Build KGW42R**. Needless to say it deploys fine on wear emulator. I am wondering if the latest Moto360 system update has anything to do with it.

Comment: Have you somehow filled up the internal storage of your device? Is there anything in adb logcat that might indicate what the problem is? You might want to try factory resetting the device as well.

Comment: I literally just opened the box, paired Moto360 with my S4 and tried to deploy "Hello, world!" app, which gave me error above. I tried factory reset today to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like latest SDK updates from 10/17/2014 for Android studio fixed the issue.